# rest api is generated without count or results attribute

Tags: json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I used `django rest framework` to create an api but the api being rendered does not contain `count`, `result` or `next` or `null` attributes which could be used to access the several fields in a loop. It looks like this -

```
[
{
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/clubs/1/persons/",
    "id": 1,
    "club_name": "club1",
    "persons": [
        1,
        2
    ]
},
{
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/clubs/2/persons/",
    "id": 2,
    "club_name": "club2",
    "persons": [
        1,
        4
    ]
},
]
```

But all the tutorials on the web have an api with those attributes.I'd like to access all attributes of a club is one loop. Is there something that I have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup [pagination](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/) for your API.

Note that the API changed and some post may not be up to date with current API.

Comment: I couldn't gather much from the documentation. Most of it looks like it is for next and previous, while I am more concerned about how to get the `count` and `results:` keys. Could you give me a hint about that

Comment: [PageNumberPagination](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#pagenumberpagination) or [LimitOffsetPagination](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#limitoffsetpagination) do alter the serializer response to include count / results / next / previous as shown by the documentation.

Comment: I just don't get what's stoping you from using them.